# How to set value to all child's data in firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to set SubmitCheck to "true" for all users at once.

I have so many users in this project .is this possible to set value "true" for users.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this using this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String trueValue = "true";
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ds.child("SubmitCheck").getRef().setValue(trueValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

A saw in your code that you are using the String `true` in stead of the boolean `true`. If you'll change the value of the String with a boolean in your database, than you'll need to change also this lines:

```
boolean bool = true;
ds.child("SubmitCheck").setValue(bool);
```

Comment: cannot resolve method setvalue . setvalue is red and not work